# Finding the minimizer of $I[f]=\int_1^2 (x^2 f'(x)^2+2f(x)^2)dx$

Tags: calculus-of-variations, functional-calculus

My Question is, if my solution is right.

I am trying to minimize
$$
I[f]=\int_1^2 (x^2 f'(x)^2+2f(x)^2)\,\mathrm dx
$$
with the conditions $f(1)=0$, $f(2)=1$
Assuming $f$ is the minimizer and $\epsilon \in \mathbb{R}$ I define
$g(\epsilon):=I[f+\epsilon h]=\int_1^2 x^2(f'(x)+\epsilon h'(x))^2+2(f(x)+\epsilon h(x))^2dx$
Because I assumed f is a minimum of I[f], I[f+$\epsilon$ h] hast it's minimum for $\epsilon=0$, especially g'(0)=0

Calculating the derivative gives

$g'(\epsilon)=\int_1^2 2x(f'(x)+\epsilon h'(x))^2+2x^2(f'(x)+\epsilon h'(x))^2(f''(x)+\epsilon h''(x))+4(f(x)+\epsilon h(x))(f'(x)+\epsilon h'(x))) dx$

So as a result I get
$0=g'(0)$=$\int_1^2 2x f'(x)^2+2x^2f'(x)^2f''(x)+4f(x)f'(x)dx$=$\int_1^2 f'(x)(2xf'(x)+2x^2f'(x)f''(x)+4f(x)) dx$

, so as a the answer I get $f'(x)=0$ and f(x)=c where $c \in \mathbb{R}$ which does not seem right considering the condition that f(1)=0, f(2)=1

Did I make a mistake? Thanks in advance

Comment: Why don't you use the Euler-Lagrange condition?

Comment: It looks like you've computed the derivatve incorrectly. How did you get $f''(x), h''(x)$ when you need to compute $d/d \epsilon$? I get that it should be (with one application of integration by parts) $$\int_{1}^{2} (- 2x^{2} f'' + 4f) h dx = 0 \implies -2x^{2} f'' + 4f = 0$$

Comment: @mattos yeah you are right

Answer (score 2):

You can use "Calculus of Variations" for this. Given an equation of the form:
$$J[y]=\int_{x_1}^{x_2}L(x,f,f')dx$$
the minimum is given by:
$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial f}-\frac{d}{dx}\frac{\partial L}{\partial f'}=0$$

---

In your case you have:
$$L=x^2f'(x)^2+2f(x)^2$$
and so:
$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial f}=4f$$
$$\frac{d}{dx}\frac{\partial L}{\partial f'}=\frac{d}{dx}\left(2x^2f'(x)\right)=4xf'(x)+2x^2f''(x)$$
now combing this we get:
$$4f(x)-4xf'(x)-2x^2f''(x)=0$$

---

To solve this we can first divide through by two:
$$x^2f''(x)+2xf'(x)-2f(x)=0$$
now a form of substitution like $x^n$ should make this easy to solve